# Hiding the controller path in the URL

Tags: cakephp, subdomain, url-routing, cakephp-4.x

I have these URLs:

- `https://my.example.com/api/foo`
- `https://my.example.com/api/bar`
- `https://my.example.com/api/baz`

In order to *simplify* it for the user and also to *emphasise* the different meaning I have set up these subdomains which have the same `DocumentRoot` as `https://my.example.com/`:

- `https://foo.example.com/`
- `https://bar.example.com/`
- `https://baz.example.com/`

Due to the fact I am not capable to do the final step which means the URLs are still like this:

- `https://foo.example.com/api/foo`
- `https://bar.example.com/api/bar`
- `https://baz.example.com/api/baz`

which isn't really simplifying it as the user has still to append `api/<name>` to the URL.

**My question:**

Is there a way to omit `/api/<name>` and *redirect it somehow* in the CakePHP controller so it's enough to enter `https://foo.example.com/` and this would run the code in `https://foo.example.com/api/foo`?

I can check the current subdomain using `$_SERVER ["SERVERNAME"]` so this isn't the problem.

**What makes it a bit more difficult:**

The login page is as usually accessed through `https://foo.example.com/users/login` which means when `/users/login` is a part of the URL then the *invisible redirect* must NOT be triggered. However, I think I can prevent this checking the content of the `$_SERVER` variable.

I really hope you guys understand what I mean.

PS: I don't want to use Apache's redirect as this would display the final URL `https://foo.example.com/api/foo` in the browser.

Running CakePHP 4.1.4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really see how this is more simple, if anything I'd find it to be less verbose, which is never good for a URL. Anyways, it sounds like you're looking for host bound routes, ie the `_host` option.

This would connect `/` to `foo.example.com`, `bar.example.com`, and `baz.example.com`, each to a different controller depending on the host:

```php
$routes->scope(
    '/',
    function (\Cake\Routing\RouteBuilder $builder) {
        $builder
            ->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Foo'])
            ->setHost('foo.example.com');

        $builder
            ->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Bar'])
            ->setHost('bar.example.com');

        $builder
            ->connect('/', ['controller' => 'Baz'])
            ->setHost('baz.example.com');

        $builder
            ->connect('/users/login', ['controller' => 'Users', 'action' => 'login']);
    }
);
```

The `/users/login` URL would connect to any host, as it's not being restricted, ie all of these URLs would work and point to the same controller and action:

- `foo.example.com/users/login`
- `bar.example.com/users/login`
- `baz.example.com/users/login`

That could possibly introduce further problems, like for example cookies not working if they're not scoped for all subdomains, or duplicate content as far as SEO goes. So make sure that you keep your routes as specific as possible!

Also note that resource routing won't work properly with this, as it requires a path element, ie you cannot connect resources on just `/`, eg `foo.example.com`, it would have to be `foo.example.com/resource-name`, if you'd wanted to connect to the former, each resource route would need to be connected manually.

Finally, if you're not using named routes, then you'll have to use `'_host' => 'foo.example.com'` in your URL arrays if you want to generate URLs!

See also

- **[Cookbook > Routing > Matching Specific Hostnames](https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/routing.html#matching-specific-hostnames)**

Comment: I cannot again thank you enough. This is exactly what I was looking for. I had to add `action` to the `connect` option but it works perfectly. @simple: I didn't explain all thoughts. @SEO: This is not a problem as we talk here about closed area. Search engines will be even forbidden to crawl it. I tested now a lot and it seems it works.